# win10 ghc-mod fails to install (ghc 8.2.1)

Tags: haskell

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghc-mod-5.8.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of ghc-mod-5.8.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: ghc-mod => base<4.10 && >=4.6.0.1)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, ghc-mod, syb
```

What happend? And, what should I do?

Comment: Install via haskell stack .

Comment: You can try to `cabal install ghc-mod --allow-newer` though I would also use `stack` - clone the git repository,  `stack init` and edit the stack yaml, to allow newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/issues/907) for ghc-mod,

> GHC 8.2.1 is not supported yet, hence the base<4.10 constraint.

(as of mid-Sept. 2917) and,

the feature support for 8.2.1 is added this to the [v5.9.0.0 milestone](https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/milestone/8).